# PowerShell & Batch Files With User Input

Tags: powershell, batch-file

OK first a thanks to **nex84** for answering my last question and all those that gave input as well at this link https://superuser.com/a/1051727/569550...

I now have a new question but it ties with the same code as the one in the link.

I have created a script that will remove text from a file name and replace it with new text or a blank.

This was stated in the last question following the link I gave.  I have added a user input so the user can input what the text is to be removed and what they want to add.

I get the removal part correct but I am having trouble with the addition of new text to the file name. Any suggestions...

The code below works for the removed but when the rename comes in the script adds "$Rename" to the file name instead of what the user inputs.

Example: If the user removed "-Layout1" but add "-Model" to the file name we get:

```
BLABLA-Layout1.pdf ==>  BLABLA$Replace.pdf
```

Code:

```
CD C:\TempPDF 
$Filter = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input Text To Be Removed' 
$Rename = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input Text To Be Added' 
Write-Host "You input server '$Filter' and '$Rename'" 
Get-ChildItem -Filter "*$Filter*" -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.name -replace "$Filter",'$Rename' }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Single quotes in Powershell delimits only string values. In this case use double-quotes when passing variable $Rename to the file name.

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter "*$Filter*" -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.name -replace "$Filter","$Rename" }
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for the quick answer. This works perfectly now. All I need to do now is wrap it in an exe and I can distribute it to my coworkers. You guys are awesome! Thanks again.

Comment: This code lets me get away from downloading all the Renaming Utilities out there. Thanks again.